# Right way to tell all directives that data has already loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have SPA and on the first page I load a big data object from the REST service.

The first page consists of the main part which resolved by controller, set of directives in the current scope which render some parts of received object and a header directive in the $rootscope which also render some part of received data.

I call API in the controller and when all data will be loaded I should notify about it all related directives for rendering loaded data.

Now I use `$watch()` and `$watchGroup()` for the same scope directives and `$rootScope.$broadcast()` for the header from the $rootscope.

*Is there any more gracefully solution for it?*

*What is the best way to do this?*

Comment: Does the directives use 2way binding and you bind the data that way?

Comment: I would keep just the `$broadcast`

Comment: For storing received data from API and accumulated data by user I use a service (StateService). All directives have an isolated scope. Some of them binding data from the controller scope. In this case I use `$watch()`. Some of them also have a direct access to the StateService, so they take received data from the service and save accumulated data to the service. Is it a good solution?

Comment: For Example in case header directive broadcast handler fires I fetch data for directive from the StateService.

Comment: @Mosho How to share data in this case? Through the `$broadcast`?

Comment: Shared data should be in a service

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use case for ngResource, which is an official Angular module for REST resources. I'd recommend you create a service for your resource like:

```
app.factory('Widget', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/v1/widgets/:id');
});
```

Then you can use it in your controller to handle the loading of your data.

```
app.controller('WidgetController', function ($scope, Widget) {
    $scope.widgets = Widget.query({active: true});
});
```

In your views/templates/whatever, can bind right to `widgets`, which will be an array of widgets that match the query. The array will be empty while the widgets load, then it will be populated with the results -- and the binding will automatically update.

You can also bind to `widgets.$resolved` which (essentially) indicates whether the resource has finished loading or not.

Check out more about ngResource [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource).